# Is there a way that a Dismissible swipe can be occur one a time only and not multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart

Since Dismissible can detect multiple gestures of swiping, what I want to achieve is how to do it like one at a time only and not multiple swiping. Thank you so much in advance

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // make it dismissible
            return Dismissible(
               background: Container(
                   color: Colors.red,
                   child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                              // white text
                              const Text(
                                "Delete",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                   direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                  key: Key(snapshot.data![index].id.toString()),
                 onDismissed: (direction) {
                          // remove the item from the data source
               accountSettings.deleteAccount(
              snapshot.data![index].id.toString());
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For that case, I used a simple hack.

onDismissed, which is called when the widget is dismissed, you can use this property to set a flag that will prevent the widget from being dismissed again.

```
bool isDismissed = false;

Dismissible(
  key: Key(item.id.toString()),
  onDismissed: (direction) {
    if (!isDismissed) {
      // Set the flag to prevent multiple dismissals
      isDismissed = true;

      // Do something when the widget is dismissed
      // ...
    }
  },
  child: // your child widget here
)
```

Then after you want to active onDismissed
try

```
isDismissed = true;
```

I think this will solve your problem.